# Adobe on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wine, firewall, adobe

I want to install Adobe Master Collection CS6 on Ubuntu. 
I've installed Wine. ( the newest version. What I have allready done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks 

winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko

cd /home/user/path/to/installer
wine Set-up.exe
```

)

then I get allways this error Message:

```
Installation Failed

Your installation encounter Errors

**Installer failed to initialize. This Could be due to a missing file.**

More troubleshooting tips:
1. Restart your computer:
2. Exit all application including startup items, virus checking and firewall software.
3. launch the installer and reinstall your application.
```

I tried to stop firewall softwares on ubuntu ( I haven't installed smth. on my own.. I just looked for software, who is  allready installed. I've done:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

and restarted my Computer

but still the Error-message.

How to solve it ?

Comment: Why don't you just use PlayOnLinux? PlayOnLinux makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do believe that Adobe stuff (like photoshop) has a bad reputation of working with Wine. The same thing happens with iTunes. The latest compatible version of iTunes that works with Wine is version 8. 8! THE LATEST RELEASE IS LIKE, 12.1.1!!!!! I would suggest trying an earlier version of Master Collection, and if that doesn't work, try looking around for an alternative program that does the same thing. Also, try installing Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center, (after deleting the one you just installed) instead of from a possibly outdated PPA.
Oh, and also try PlayOnLinux.